# Is there a closed formula for this summation?

Tags: calculus, summation

I have the summation

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}$$

And I don't know how to find a closed formula for it. Any ideas?

Comment: It's actually a know [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: That is the generalized harmonic number $H_n^{(2)}$.

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk Basel's problem is the evaluation of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k^{-2}$ while the question here is a closed formula for $g(n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{-2}$. Ok, arguably one may say that, if we had a closed form for $g(n)$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)$ would not be a "problem", but that link does not talk exactly of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite series $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}$$ has a closed form.  But the finite series does not.

Sometimes we may write it using the ["trigamma" function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function), but this is not much beyond the definition.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \psi^{(1)}(n+1)
$$

Comment: +1. I'll take $\underline{this\ one}$ as a closed expression.